# NodeJS '@azure/storage-blob': How do set blobcontentdisposition property for the existing blobs

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

Please advise, how can I set the blobcontentdisposition property for the existing blobs in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
blockBlobClient.setHTTPHeaders({"blobContentType": contentType!, "blobContentDisposition": "attachment; filename=" + downloadFileName})

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(fileStream, undefined, undefined, {blobHTTPHeaders: {blobContentType: contentType!}})
```

**For Example:**

```js
const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/jpeg', blobContentDisposition: "attachment; filename=package.jpg" } };
    const uploadBlobResponse =await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath,blobOptions);
```

In `UploadStream`, **`blobContentDisposition`** property should be set explicitly. Otherwise, Service might clean up **`contentDispostion`** already set with `setHTTPHeaders`.

Refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/8553) for more information.